# how to see the object function with tensorflowJS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

so in every javascript object there are functions and data we can access like and in tenserflow you can either use the CDN or the npm package

my question is how can i see the suggested object or function or data in the frontend?

in the backend since it's installed i can see the functions inside it but in the frontend it's not possbile which leads to lot of typeos and errors because no suggestions how can i fix this and be able to see them?

excepting [what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCXuU.png)

what i get [what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhvRc.png)